# Xamarin.forms error while app built

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I am trying to run quickBlox samaple app using xamarin in iphone which is implemented in xamarin.forms.I am getting following error

> XamarinForms/XamarinForms.QbChat.iOS/MTOUCH: Error MT2002: Failed to
>   resolve "System.Void
>   Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlFilePathAttribute::.ctor(System.String)"
>   reference from "Xamarin.Forms.Xaml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null" (MT2002) (XamarinForms.QbChat.iOS)

Comment: Did you update the Xamarin.Forms NuGet packages? Maybe you forgot to update it on your shared or your platform project? Make sure the versions are in sync.

Comment: see this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31402323/3901620

Comment: Yes...thank you.its working now